# Reported value in block diverges from actual block’s value

Tags: mastering-bitcoin

In the book "Mastering Bitcoin", 3rd edition, on page 50, Example 3-6 shows

> Total value in block:  10322.07722534.

This is block 775072, and blockchain.com shows this block’s Output Value is
5,863.01 BTC. What could explain this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other blockchain explorers agree with blockchain.com's valuation.

[Older versions of rpc_block.py](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/commit/4d15f0aad33822ed5d4844a0748b4d3bf5df54b6#diff-5f6ed4a47b6ffee283dcefb6ff77f2b2c5f1c6feb4942754580f171506107f02) had

```
blockheight = 277316
```

So I wondered if maybe the total was overlooked in the editing of the revisions and the example output is the total for 277316 not 775072.

But [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/blocks/btc/277316) says the total for block 277316 is ₿10,296.9863. Closer but not a match.

I would just assume that it is an error in the book - if so, you could probably report it through github to get it fixed.